# How to move mouse to coordinates based on JFrame?

Tags: java, mouse, awtrobot

Im attempting to move the mouse to the middle of my JFrame when ever I want.  I originally thought I could use Robot to move the mouse to the desired location but using

```
robot.mouseMove(300, 400);
```

moves the mouse to 300, 400 with 0, 0 as the top left hand corner of my screen.  I want 0, 0 to be the top left hand corner of the JFrame not the entire screen.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried that?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLocation(100, 100);
frame.setSize(500, 500);
frame.setVisible(true);
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(frame.getX() + 250, frame.getY() + 250);
} catch (AWTException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've tried that, and this works for me !

Comment: System.out.println(frame.getX());

Comment: yes if your frame was at position (0,0) !! if your frame was at another position then this method will return something different from 0. Try that: 
`System.out.println(frame.getX());
  
  frame.setLocation(40, 40);
  
  System.out.println(frame.getX());`
Frist getX() will return 0, and after move getX() will return 40.